# Conditional Formatting for cells that are 50%<

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I am trying to get conditional formation to highlight cells in column G that are 50% greater than the corresponding cell in column D. I have tied to use a formula to determine which cells to format with the formula below but it only works for one cell. I want to apply the formatting to all the cells in column G. Formula:=$G$39>=(0.5*$D$39)

Any recommendations?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change the Applies to $G$4:$G$77 and the formula to `=$G4>=(0.5*$D4)`  Conditional formatting will iterate the row correctly

Comment: The formula looks better but now it's highlighting cells that are not greater than 50% too.  :(

Comment: Did you use `$G$4:$G$77` as the Applies to:  and `=$G4>=(0.5*$D4)` as the formula?  If your first row in the applies to does not match the row in the formula then they will be offset.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to apply the conditional formatting for the column G?

Try this method:

1. select the **Column G**- go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**
   [image]
2. select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**- enter the formula and set the format:

> =G1>=(0.5*D1)

[image]
[image]